# How to add a sentence at the top of a text file using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the project

```
@echo off
set /p s=Enter the name of the account you want to search for:

start https://www.facebook.com/%s%
start https://www.instagram.com/%s%
start https://www.tiktok.com/@%s%
start https://twitter.com/%s%
start https://story.snapchat.com/@%s%

echo %s% >> History.txt
```

I want to put a title at the top of the text file

If you make the code like this

```
@echo off
set /p s=Enter the name of the account you want to search for:

start https://www.facebook.com/%s%
start https://www.instagram.com/%s%
start https://www.tiktok.com/@%s%
start https://twitter.com/%s%
start https://story.snapchat.com/@%s%
echo This is the History > History.txt
echo %s% >> History.txt
```

It will not save usernames, because every time it deletes everything and then adds a title

I want him to add the title only the first time, when he creates the file

Comment: If you're specifically adding a title as the first line of the file, then surely all you would need to do is to check to see if the file exists, and has content. If it doesn't use `(Echo This is the History&Echo(%s%) 1>"History.txt"`, if it does use `(Echo(%s%) 1>>"History.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this code :

```bat
@echo off
Title Searching account
set /p s=Enter the name of the account you want to search for:
If Not Exist "%~dp0History.txt" (echo This is the History)>"%~dp0History.txt"
If Exist "%~dp0History.txt" (echo %s%)>>"%~dp0History.txt"

start https://www.facebook.com/%s%
start https://www.instagram.com/%s%
start https://www.tiktok.com/@%s%
start https://twitter.com/%s%
start https://story.snapchat.com/@%s%
```

Comment: Just be aware, that just because a file or directory exists, it does not mean that it has content. An empty `history.txt` file may exist, but would obviously not have the title line required according to the question parameters. That line would therefore need to be added, before the username is redirected!